# Xamarin studio - terminal won't open with correct project when 'play' pressed

Tags: macos, xamarin

i have just started using Xamarin studio on the Mac x. I was following the tutorials on youtube. I made one project (the calculator) which worked fine when I pressed the 'play' button and opened in the terminal. In the new project when I press play it just opens up the terminal with 'hello world'. Now, even when i go back to the calculator project, same message - 'hello world'. I don't know how to get it to work, i've tried opening a new project and restarting, but still doesn't work :s

Please help, thanks!!!

Comment: Have you set the Calculator project to be the startup project? You can do that by right clicking on the project in the Solution window and selecting Set as Startup Project.

Comment: That seemed to have done the trick, thanks mate.